# Integrate PaySimple in my asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway, payment-processing

I need to integrate PaySimple site in my asp.net website. My requirement is to just capture information required by PaySimple site and direct user to the PaySimple Website to complete the transaction and return back to my site with response message.
 
I want to know what are the parameters required by the Paysimple website and how to pass these parameters to paysimple site. Please suggest me a way to do the things. I am using c#.

Answer (score 1):

They have API that is based on well-known technologies like SOAP or JSON, so  you can use WebReference for accessing their web service and getting or sending data to it. You can read more about API [here](https://sandbox-api.paysimple.com/3.00/help/PaySimple_3.00_APIDeveloperDocumentation.pdf)